# How to access localhost offline?

Tags: localhost

I have set up XAMPP server and I'm working on few sites in my local server. I see that I cant access localhost unless connected to internet.

Is there any way I can access localhost without connecting to internet? I'm using opera. If you have solutions specific to browser please mention it.

I'm using Windows 7.

Thanks,

Comment: This should work anyway. Did you edit your hosts file? I take it you're using windows? Try 127.0.0.1

Comment: I'm using windows machine. Tried to access http://127.0.0.1. But not able to connect

Comment: something is not configured properly.  Localhost/127.0.0.1 should work as long as TCPIP is installed, regardless of connectivity

Answer (score -3):

Yea there is a way but first you needed to connect to internet then run  apache or other Then go to local host and then save the webpage,now you can access your php files offline

Comment: How does this answer the question of how to access localhost offline when working on a few websites in non-IT guy's local server?